# 15 votes difference

Tags: discussion

please take look at these questions;

- [Are human fetuses more likely to be male?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/768/are-human-fetuses-more-likely-to-be-male)
- [Why do we have more male infant born?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27582/why-do-we-have-more-male-infant-born)

These two question are similar, even one of them is marked as duplicate of other one. the first question with **(431)views** and the second one with **(123)views**.

so,Why should be 15 vote difference between these?

Comment: It depends on some factors: How is the question seen by people, how much other questions are asked on that day (if there are many, they go down in the list rather fast and get not as much attention) and so on.

Comment: @Chris You are right,but can these reasons cause 15 votes difference and I want to know why you and some other users marked the first question as duplicate?.

Comment: The number of views is also a factor. I can tell you from my own experience that questions that are popular on the network (meaning they get a lot of views) tend to get much more votes.

Comment: Ii is not now 15

Comment: The first Q is several years older (more time to gather votes) from when BioSE was new and voting patterns might have been different then (early community building process). Q's that are picked up as a *hot network* Q also generally get a lot of views and votes, but I don't know if this was the case here.

Comment: Because that's the way things played out. People see the questions they see and vote the way they vote. We can't add or remove votes from posts. I don't really see what you're asking here.